# Using parseTest in megaparsec 7.0.4

Tags: haskell, megaparsec

Advent of Code means I'm using megaparsec for the first time in a while. And things have changed around a fair bit since last time. Assuming

```
import qualified Text.Megaparsec as MP
import qualified Text.Megaparsec.Char as C
```

I tried

```
MP.parseTest (C.char '+') "+"
```

in GHCI, which gives the following rather unhelpful error message:

```
interactive>:121:1: error:
* Ambiguous type variable `e0' arising from a use of `MP.parseTest'
  prevents the constraint `(MP.ShowErrorComponent
                              e0)' from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `e0' should be.
  These potential instance exist:
    one instance involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
* In the expression: MP.parseTest (C.char '+') "+"
  In an equation for `it': it = MP.parseTest (C.char '+') "+"

<interactive>:121:15: error:
* Ambiguous type variable `e0' arising from a use of `C.char'
  prevents the constraint `(Ord e0)' from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `e0' should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (Either a b)
      -- Defined in `Data.Either'
    instance Ord Ordering -- Defined in `ghc-prim-0.5.3:GHC.Classes'
    instance Ord Integer
      -- Defined in `integer-gmp-1.0.2.0:GHC.Integer.Type'
    ...plus 25 others
    ...plus 131 instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
* In the first argument of `MP.parseTest', namely `(C.char '+')'
  In the expression: MP.parseTest (C.char '+') "+"
  In an equation for `it': it = MP.parseTest (C.char '+') "+"
```

Am I using this correctly? What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest versions of "megaparsec" support [custom error types](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-7.0.4/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#v:fancyFailure) defined by the user. The [`ParsecT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-7.0.4/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#t:ParsecT) type is parameterized by the type of the custom errors. To support pretty-printing (like in [`parseTest`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-7.0.4/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#v:parseTest)) such custom errors must be instances of the `Ord` and [`ShowErrorComponent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-7.0.4/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Error.html#t:ShowErrorComponent) typeclasses.

If we never throw any custom errors, the error type remains polymorphic. But at the end, when printing the results, we must provide a concrete type. We can use the uninhabited type `Void` from the "void" package, and inform the type checker by using an explicit type signature.

The documentation [recommends](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-7.0.4/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html) defining a type synonym like `type Parser = Parsec Void Text` and using it in your signatures.

Another way of avoiding the ambiguity is by using [visible type application](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-08-visible-type-application-ghc8.html):

```
Prelude Text.Megaparsec Data.Void> :t parseTest
parseTest
  :: (ShowErrorComponent e, Show a, Stream s) =>
     Parsec e s a -> s -> IO ()
Prelude Text.Megaparsec Data.Void> :set -XTypeApplications
Prelude Text.Megaparsec Data.Void> :t parseTest @Void
parseTest @Void
  :: (Show a, Stream s) => Parsec Void s a -> s -> IO ()
```